# enum won't work with template like code

Tags: c++, templates, enums

I tried to mimic the boost::iterator_range and boost::counting_iterator by STL. the code seems to work but when i try to pass enum elements to it, I get these errors:

> Error 2   error C2100: illegal indirection
>   Error 1   error C2675: unary '++' : '`anonymous-namespace'::Block_Edges'
>   does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to
>   the predefined operator

how to fix these errors?

the code

```
#include <iostream>

namespace
{
    enum Block_Edges
    {
        FROM = 0,
        TO = 4,
    };
};

template<typename T, bool enable = std::is_integral<T>::value>
struct range_impl
{
    struct iterator
    {
        const T operator * ()const noexcept
        {
            return value;
        }

        iterator& operator ++() noexcept
        {
            ++value;
            return *this;
        }

        friend  const bool operator != (const iterator& lhs, const iterator& rhs) noexcept
        {
            return lhs.value != rhs.value;
        }

        T value;
    };

    std::size_t size() const
    {
        return last - first;
    }

    const iterator begin()const noexcept
    {
        return{ first };
    }

        const iterator end()const noexcept
    {
        return{ last };
    }

    T first;
    T last;
};

template<typename T>
struct range_impl<T, false>
{
    range_impl(T first, T last)
        : first(first)
        , last(last)
    {}

    std::size_t size() const
    {
        return std::distance(first, last);
    }

    const T begin()const noexcept
    {
        return{ first };
    }

        const T end()const noexcept
    {
        return{ last };
    }

    T first;
    T last;
};

template<typename T>
range_impl<T>  range(T first, T last) noexcept
{
    return{ first, last };
}

int main()
{
    //for (const auto& i : range(0, 4)) // PASS
    //{
    //  std::cout << '\n' << i << ':';
    //  for (const auto& j : range(0, 4))
    //  {
    //      std::cout << j << ' ';
    //  }
    //}

    for (const auto& i : range(Block_Edges::FROM, Block_Edges::TO)) // FAILED
    {
        std::cout << '\n' << i << ':';
        for (const auto& j : range(Block_Edges::FROM, Block_Edges::TO))
        {
            std::cout << j << ' ';
        }
    }
}
```

**solved:**

just cast as int.

Comment: If the error message says you havent defined an operator required for the template, then maybe you should define it?

Comment: @Happy .. OK but i already define it in `range_impl`

Comment: @Happy .. i solved it. it need cast only. but why it needs casting. really bad error messages

Comment: No, you are doing it wrong, let me post an answer in a bit.

Comment: *"really bad error messages"* - seems fine to me - what do you think would be better...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 errors:

this function is missing:

```
Block_Edges& operator++(Block_Edges& e)
{
    return e = static_cast<Block_Edges>(e + 1);
}
```

Enums are not considered integral types in C++, so you have to also use `std::is_enum`:

```
template<typename T,
         bool enable = std::is_integral<T>::value || std::is_enum<T>::value>
struct range_impl
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/5fGiv8)

Comment: thanks a lot, but i went to anothor problem `for (const auto& i : range(Block_Edges::FROM, Block_Edges::TO - 1))` won't compile.

Comment: @MORTAL: `Block_Edges::TO - 1` is an `int` whereas `Block_Edges::FROM` is an `enum`, so `T` cannot be deduced for `range<T>`. you may change `range` to `template<typename T1, typename T2>
range_impl<typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type>  range(T1 first, T2 last) noexcept` or call `range<int>(Block_Edges::FROM, Block_Edges::TO - 1)` (or cast `Block_Edges::TO - 1` to the enum)

Comment: great ... i will implement those. i get it work by `for (const auto& i : range(Block_Edges::FROM + 0, Block_Edges::TO - 1))` but i don't like it.